# Creating a function which returns the highest product of three numbers

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon, I was given a task to create to a function which returns the multiply of three highest numbers in array.

The only way of how I manage to do this.

```
var stringArray = new Array('8','-1','2','2','0','14');

// Converting strings to numbers
var intArray = stringArray.map(Number);

// Sorting out and multiplying result
var first = intArray.sort(function(a,b){return b-a})[0]; 
var second = intArray.sort(function(a,b){return b-a})[1]; 
var third = intArray.sort(function(a,b){return b-a})[2]; 
console.log(first * second * third); // 224 is result
```

Any way of how I can do it in a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
let result = stringArray.map(Number).sort((a,b)=>b-a).slice(0,3).reduce((acc,a)=> acc*a,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let stringArray = new Array('8','-1','2','2','0','14');

// Converting strings to numbers
let intArray = stringArray.map(Number);

const result = intArray.sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(0,3).reduce((acc,cur) =>  acc*cur);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.